# Syntastic won't recognize C++ WxWidgets headers

Tags: filetype-c++, plugin-syntastic

The library it is not recognizing is WxWidgets

my ~/.vimrc File

```
execute pathogen#infect()
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

I import Wx like this

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/menu.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
```

The Error is

```
gui.cpp|1 col 10 error| fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
```

I already included the Path of Wx like this

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs =['/usr/local/lib']
```

And i can Compile it with out any Problems

Comment: Welcome to  Vim :-) It would be good if you could be more explicitly about your symptoms. Could explain what is your input and what do you expect.? Maybe also what you already tried.

Comment: Is `wx/wx.h` actually at `/usr/include/wx/wx.h` or `/usr/local/include/wx/wx.h`? On my system at least it's in `/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/wx.h`; I think most systems use a version subdirectory like that for WxWidgets (although the exact path may be slightly different on your system). So try adding `/usr/include/wx-3.0` (or whatever the exact path is on your system) to `g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs`.

Comment: Thx yes it where the wrong path i also have on the other path some wxWidgets stuff but now it works

Comment: @Benn1x can you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem where that i had included the wrong path
as @Martin Tournoij said the path where /usr/include/wx-3.x

The include in the  .vimrc looks now like this

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs =['/usr/local/lib',' /usr/include/wx-3.1','/usr/include/wx-3.0']
```

And this solved the use for me